# Dynamically updating checkboxes option by drop down input in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, filter

I am trying to dynamically update the checkboxes option by the dropdown input. For an example if the user selects 1 then the checkbox 1 will not appear but the rest will, and so on.

**HTML**

```
<tr><th><label for="dropdown">Dropdown:</label></th><td><select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>

</select></td></tr>

<li><label for="id_checkbox_0"><input id="id_checkbox_0" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 1</label></li>
<li><label for="id_checkbox_1"><input id="id_checkbox_1" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" /> 2</label></li>
<li><label for="id_checkbox_2"><input id="id_checkbox_2" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" /> 3</label></li>
<li><label for="id_checkbox_3"><input id="id_checkbox_3" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" /> 4</label></li>
```

**JQuery**

```
     $("#dropdown").change(function() {

         var index = $(':selected', this).index();
         $('#id_checkbox_'+index).parent().hide(); 

 });
```

Heres JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/ffs408u6/

Thanks!

Comment: html is invalid, `li` must have proper parent, `ul` or `ol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function() {

     var index = $(':selected', this).index();
     $('#id_checkbox_'+index).parents('li').hide();
     $('input:not(#id_checkbox_'+index+')').parents('li').show();

 });
```

This will hide the corresponding checkbox, and reveal the others that don't match. Note that selecting the

element using parents('li') will hide the entire list item, not just the checkbox.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5oedargs/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `closest()` and hide that specific `li`:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
    $("li").show(); // show all
    var index = $(':selected', this).index();
    $('#id_checkbox_'+index).closest("li").hide(); // hide which matches the selector

 });
```

### UPDATED FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ffs408u6/1/